# Harddrive check going-on?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I have a server that has suddenly become unusable (responds very slowly to requests). It seems to be related to some on-going RAID check. Here is what I get when I run `cat /proc/mdstat` :

```
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty] 
md1 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      10238912 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      965994432 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      [>....................]  check =  0.7% (7714624/965994432) finish=581611.7min speed=27K/sec
```

Apparently some sort of check is going on. What is this and how may I stop that / avoid that it slows down the server?

Comment: 27K/sec.. at that rate, it'll take over a year to check the RAID.  Take a look at your logs, something strange is probably going on.  One of those disks might be failing.

Comment: Ok what logs should I look at? It's now reached a speed of 5000K/sec. Still slow but better

Comment: `dmesg` might be able to tell you.